# Creating a SQL Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm having trouble creating a query.

I need to create a SQL query where ProductID = prodSelect (user choice) and EndTime = Null and StartTime < 3 hours from the current time.

This is what I have so far. Could someone help me figure it out?

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT TimeID " & _
    "FROM tblLunchTime " & _
    "WHERE ProductionID = prodSelect 
       AND EndTime = NULL 
       AND StartTime < (Now - 0/0/0000 3: 00: 00 AM")
```

Comment: Do we get a hint as to which database you are using? Note it should be `EndTime IS NULL`.

Comment: Red Filter's right - we need to know what database this is for in order to provide how to modify the current date.

Comment: Don't you want addition rather than subtraction : (Now + 0/0/0000 3: 00: 00 AM")

Comment: What do you mean which database? Just a regular database in SQL.

Comment: Is it Oracle? MySQL? MS-SQL? SQLite? PostgreSQL? Firebird? Paradox? Pervasive? MS-Access? I can't promise they will all handle time-values the same way.

Comment: @BioXhazard There are different types of databases which have slight differences in SQL syntax and often less-slight differences in what date-handling functions are available. From the look of your code though, I would guess you are using Transact SQL.

Comment: Reason we ask is that SQL stands for "Structured Query Language", **not** "Standardized Query Language"

Comment: Heh, of course that was my last guess... Also, I'd hardly call MS-Access "regular".

Comment: @BioXhazard: I edited the question so that it still has the original query, that way the question makes sense to people who come along later. If you want to include the solution, please add it below the original query, and put "Update: solution with help from Andomar's answer" or something to that effect

Comment: Is this not exactly the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152981/invalid-argument-error-msaccess-and-sql ? With the additional information in the other one that your data is stored in a "SQL database" not in Access/Jet/ACE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition `AND EndTime = NULL` always evaluates to unknown.  Instead, use:

```
AND EndTime is NULL
```

Then, you probably should tell the database how to parse the datetime string.  This would work on MS Access (to require StartTime to be more than 3 hours in the past):

```
AND StartTime < dateadd('h',-3, now);
```

Per your comment, here is a full query:

```
SELECT TimeID 
FROM tblLunchTime 
WHERE ProductionID = 1 
AND EndTime IS NULL 
AND StartTime < DATEADD('h',-3,now)
```

The problem might be your prodId; I'm not sure what it's supposed to mean.  You might try to use it as a variable, like

```
"WHERE ProductionID = " & prodId & " " & _
```

Comment: @BioXhazard: What happens when you add -3 (hours) to the current time? Do you get an answer that's 3 hours in the future or an answer that's 3 hours in the past? I suppose if there was a `datesubstract` function you could call `datesubtract(hour,3,getdate())`...

Comment: There's a [McFly joke](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088763/) in here somewhere...

Comment: That doesn't make sense. How would a negative number increase time?

Comment: @BioXhazard: It doesn't increase time. Adding -3 hours to the current time gives you a time that was 3 hours *prior* to the current time.

Comment: Well that's probably because the solution was posted *before* you said you were using MS-Access and Andomar also specified his solution was for *SQL Server*, which does work a bit differently than Access. Now that I've retagged this as "ms-access" someone with Access knowledge might post a working solution.

Comment: @BioXhazard, FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: Edited for MS Access.  I thought everyone had a copy of Access on his pc anyway ;)

Comment: Could you post the whole expression into one line for MSAccess? Mine just gives an invalid argument error.

Answer (score 0):

As I said [in the other version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152981/invalid-argument-error-msaccess-and-sql), I think you should calculate the date/time criterion before you concatenate. Otherwise, you're passing it off to the server to do. I would do the same even if the data store was Jet/ACE.