# Invalid Argument Error: MSAccess and SQL

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to access certain lines from my SQL database from MSAccess and I keep getting an Invalid Argument Error on this line:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT TimeID " & _
    "FROM tblLunchTime " & _
    "WHERE ProductionID = prodSelect AND EndTime is NULL AND StartTime < dateAdd('h', 3, NOW())", [dbSeeChanges])
```

Is something not right in this?

```
Private Sub cmdClockEnd_Click()

'Check if a group has been selected.
If frmChoice.value = 0 Then

    MsgBox "Please select a production line."

    End

End If

'Setup form for user input.
lblEnd.Visible = True

'Save end of lunch value.
lblEnd.Caption = Format(Now, "MMM/DD/YY hh:mm:ss AMPM")

'Declare database variables.
Dim dbName As DAO.Database
Dim strValuesQuery As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim prodSelect As String
Dim sSQL As String
Dim timeValue As String
Set dbName = CurrentDb

'Get values of Production Line.
If frmChoice.value = 1 Then

prodSelect = "L2"

ElseIf frmChoice.value = 2 Then

prodSelect = "L3"

End If

'Get the last TimeID with the following parameters.
sSQL = "SELECT TimeID " & _
    "FROM tblLunchTime " & _
    "WHERE ProductionID = prodSelect AND EndTime is NULL AND StartTime < #" & DateAdd("h", 3, Now()) & "#"

Set rs = dbName.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbSeeChanges)

strValuesQuery = _
                    "UPDATE tblLunchTime " & _
                    "SET EndTime = '" & Now & "'" & _
                    "WHERE TimeID = " & rs![TimeID] & " "

'Turn warning messages off.
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

'Execute Query.
DoCmd.RunSQL strValuesQuery

'Turn warning messages back on.
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

Comment: What is prodSelect? Where is it defined? That's my first guess as to what's wrong.

Comment: Do you mean "WHERE ProductionID = " & prodSelect & " AND ... ?

Comment: prodSelect is the selected togglebutton on the form. 

Dim prodSelect As String
prodSelect = frmChoice.value

Comment: prodSelect is text, so you need quotes, see my answer below.

Comment: Nope. Still got invalid argument.

Comment: Did you get rid of dbSeeChanges, or at least put it in the right place?

Comment: One of your many issues was 'Set rs = dbName.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbSeeChanges)' where you didn't have a type (or a comma) between the SQL and the option (dbSeeChanges) - finally corrected in HansUP's answer...

Comment: I had this same error when inserting into an SQL table from an Access table while doing a SQL upgrade. It turned out to be a corrupt record in the Access table. I had to do a repair and compact, then delete the record before it would migrate successfully!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be confusion about tblLunchTime ... whether it is a native Jet/ACE table or a link to a table in another database.  Please show us the output from this command:

```
Debug.Print CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblLunchTime").Connect
```

You can paste that line into the Immediate Window and press the enter key to display the response.  (You can open the Immediate Window with CTRL+g keystroke combination.)

Just in case the response starts with "*ODBC*", suggest you try this line in your code:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
```

**Update**: Now that you're past that hurdle, suggest you change your approach with the UPDATE statement.  Don't turn off warnings; try something like this instead:

```
'Execute Query. '
CurrentDb.Execute strValuesQuery, dbFailOnError
```

And add an error handler to deal with any errors captured by dbFailOnError.

Comment: @BioXHazard Had you read the links and comments made by me 18 hours ago, it would have been easier.

Comment: Like I said, I did. But I removed it after it crashed Access and when things started getting changed in the SQL statement. Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

You need to put prodSelect outside the quotes:

```
"WHERE ProductionID = " & prodSelect & " AND ...
```

It is nearly always best to say:

```
sSQL="SELECT TimeID " & _
    "FROM tblLunchTime " & _
    "WHERE ProductionID = " & prodSelect & _
    " AND EndTime is NULL AND StartTime < dateAdd('h', 3, NOW())"
''Debug.print sSQL
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
```

You can see the advantage in the use of Debug.Print.

AHA prodSelect is text! You need quotes!

```
sSQL="SELECT TimeID " & _
    "FROM tblLunchTime " & _
    "WHERE ProductionID = '" & prodSelect & _
    "' AND EndTime is NULL AND StartTime < dateAdd('h', 3, NOW())"
```

Comment: See edit. Check the resulting SQL string, you can even paste it into the query design window, SQL view.

Comment: What is sSQL? What should I declare it as?

Comment: It is a string to hold your sql string.

Comment: I got invalid argument for Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL, [dbSeeChanges])

Comment: Did you check the immediate window (ctrl+G) for the sSQL string? You will need to uncomment Debug.Print ...

Comment: I would also get rid of [dbSeeChanges] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243019(office.12).aspx

Comment: It wouldn't let me run without having dbSeeChanges.

Comment: It is in the wrong place: expression.OpenRecordset(Name, Type, Options, LockEdit). I am not sure what it sees as Type = 512

Comment: Try Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL, ,dbSeeChanges)

Comment: This seems to work, too: Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL, options:=dbSeeChanges)

Comment: @HansUp why add dbSeeChanges? If it did not run without it, it is for some other reason, because it is in the wrong place. I think this is confusing the issue.

Comment: @Remou Ensure dbSeeChanges is passed as Options rather than Type.

Comment: @HansUp It is not needed. If something is needed it is a Type, because that is what it was in as. This is just confusing the whole thing, i reckon.

Comment: @Remou In my testing CurrentDb.OpenRecorset(sSQL, dbSeeChanges) gave me the invalid argument error same as BioXhazard.  The changes I suggested make my error go away.

Comment: @HansUp Please see comments above: I would also get rid of [dbSeeChanges] msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/… – Remou 43 mins ago ::: It wouldn't let me run without having dbSeeChanges. – BioXhazard 38 mins ago
 
It wouldn't let me run without having dbSeeChanges.

Comment: Like I said, this is confusing the issue. It should run without *any* additon to the SQL string.

Comment: @Remou I do not understand why dbSeeChanges should be required.  However, BioXhazard claims it is.  **IF** he is going to include dbSeeChanges, make sure to pass it as options rather than type.

Comment: @HansUp It *cannot* be required, because it was in the wrong place.

Comment: I have been informed when programming Access using SQL Server via ODBC that my recordsets needed to be opened with the dbSeeChanges option. I don't know why, or what it does, but my recordsets would not work without it. I've made it a normal part of creating recordsets against SQL Server. The newer SQL Server native client may eliminate the need for it -- I don't know, because all my SQL Server projects are older versions.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, David.  With an ODBC-linked SQL Server table, I couldn't make dbSeeChanges work without explicitly passing a value for type, so will suggest OP try:
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

Comment: BioXHazard has explicitly stated in other post that he or she is using MS Access, not SQL Server.

Comment: Access says it's necessary to have when using a table with a primary key. Anyway, it still doesn't work. It can't even find dbSeeChanges when you use options:=. I'm adding all of my code to the question. Maybe there's something wrong in what I'm doing.

Comment: Still got invalid argument for the line: Set rs = dbName.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbSeeChanges)

Comment: Does it make a difference if prodSelect is a string and ProductionID is nvarchar?

Comment: Just checking. What do you mean is dbSeeChanges is in the right place?

Comment: I did. But the first time I used dbOpenDynaset my MSAccess crashed.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would do the date criterion concatenation client-side, too, since it's one more thing that could go wrong:

```
  "...StartTime < #" & DateAdd("h", 3, Now()) & "#"
```

I don't know that SQL Server doesn't have DateAdd() and Now() function nor that they don't behave exactly the same as in Access, but I wouldn't take the chance -- I'd do this calculation on the client instead of handing it off to the server.